# ¿Como se la url anterior a la que estoy?

Tags: python, django

necesito saber en mi view o template, cual a sido la url anterior a la que estoy. Estoy utilizando `request.get_full_path()` pero esto me devuelve la url actual.

Hay alguna forma de conocer la url anterior?

Lo necesito por que tengo una view que puede ser llamada desde dos template diferentes, y necesito saber que template o view le ha llamado.

Un saludo

Comment: No te basta con el Http_Referer, de la forma `request.META.HTTP_REFERER`??

Comment: Sii, justo lo acabo de encontrar y me vale. Muchas gracias!!